# HTML + Identify the link clicked by user

Tags: html, anchor

In my entry.html I have 2 hyperlinks pointing to the same index.html file. Now, in index.html I need to find which link the user clicked to navigate to index html and do some operation based on the link.

entry.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Link A</a>
    <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Link B</a>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index HTML</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <p id="demo">This is it.</p>
    <script>
        // How to find the link clicked by user
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add an id to HTML links and you can track them by that id with some js code.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of query params in the links and call location.search on the redirected page to detect which link was clicked.

Refer to the code modification to your original code-

entry.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html?link=a" target="_blank">Link A</a>
    <a href="index.html?link=b" target="_blank">Link B</a>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index HTML</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        let linkName=location.search;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=linkName.split('=')[1].toUpperCase()+' was Clicked !!!';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Entry:

```
<a href="index.html#A" target="_blank">Link A</a>
<a href="index.html#B" target="_blank">Link B</a>
```

Index:

```
console.log(location.hash)
```

or

Entry:

```
<a href="index.html?link=A" target="_blank">Link A</a>
<a href="index.html?link=B" target="_blank">Link B</a>
```

Index:

```
console.log(location.search)
```

or clearer

```
const url = new URL(location.href)
console.log(url.searchParams.get("link"))
```